# How can I get Outlook 2010 to recognise an image URL to my local development environment?

Tags: url, windows-7, outlook, outlook-2010, hosts-file

Can anyone advise how I can get Outlook 2010 to recognise a URL to my local development environment?

I can access my development environment through the browser at https://crmpicco.dev however any images at that URL in my email such as this are not shown:

`<img alt="CRMPicco" title="CRMPicco" src="https://crmpicco.dev/assets/emails/logo.png">`

Currently results in: [image]

I have an entry in my Windows hosts file to point to my dev environment, so why doesn't Outlook respect this?

Are there security settings that I have to tweak to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Outlook doesn't load external images.

> can access my development environment through the browser

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. You can try to paste the image in Word and see the result. Looks like all your redirections don't make any sense in that case.

Comment: So to the same end why doesn't Word respect the `hosts` file?

Comment: Does Word do a lookup of every URL in the document before displaying it?